# Как возвратить результат из окна в другое окно?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здесь возвращается result = newWindow.ShowDialog(); в виде bool.

Но нужно возвратить результат string textBox_tag.Text;

Как делать через внешние переменные я знаю. Но хотелось бы возвращать без дополнительных переменных. Что-то вроде result.myVar = textBox_tag.Text;

```
        var newWindow = new NewDialog(this);

        Nullable<bool> result = newWindow.ShowDialog();
        // Process save file dialog box results
        if (result == true)
        {

        }
```

textBox_tag.Text

```
public partial class NewDialog : Window
{
    Window1 window1;

    public NewDialog(Window1 window1)
    {
        this.window1 = window1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Accept_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox_tag.Text;

        }
        //
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы этого не делал, тем более, что есть прекрасный для WPF паттерн MVVM. К тому же данное использование стандартных методов не по назначению может сильно сбивать с толку, уж лучше сделать открытое свойство для этого.

В остальном достаточно переписать у целевого класса метод `ShowDialog` и можете возвращать все, что только душе угодно.

```
public partial class NewDialog : Window
{
    ...
    public String ShowDialog()
    {
        base.ShowDialog();

        return textBox_tag.Text;
    }
}
```